# How to declare object type in python

Tags: python, class

I want the IDE (pycharm) to know the type of an varliable

```
class phone:

    def __init__(self,):
        self.device = None
    def connect(self,):
        self.device = samsung_object()
```

Now the IDE don't know the functions/vars used for device.
I want that in init time it will be a samsung object type.

Comment: so call `self.connect()`?

Comment: you could add `self.connect()` at the end of your `__init__` function or call `new_phone=phone().connect()` when you instantiate the `new_phone` variable

Answer (score 2):

Converting comments into code for you :)

This will works and PyCharm knows the type too..

```
class Samsung:
    def foo(self): pass

class Phone:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.device = Samsung()
    def connect(self,):
        self.device.foo() # pycharm suggest foo
```